# Server Path Information

Tags: plugins, images, directory, server, paths

I have a plugin that uses server paths to define the location of an Image Folder, however, I have decided to have a CDM or a new separate server to host my images.

Currently all the paths look like this:

`$upload_dir = '/home/www/original_domain.com/media/downloads/encrypted';`

I have tried to search the web for answers but I do not know that search queries to type in to get the answers.

The new server has a different domain and I have tried doing this:

`$upload_dir = 'http://new_domain.com/media/downloads/encrypted';`

But that does not work, is there a way to define the folder location? I believe this script can only read server paths.

Comment: You will need to provide more detail. This appears to be related to a plugin you haven't named, and possibly to a "script" of which we know nothing.

Comment: The plugin is a gallery type plugin, just like NextGen Gallery. But I was wondering if there was a way to write the server path pointing to another server.

Comment: Do you realize how many different ways there are to write a "gallery type plugin"? The answer is hidden in that mystery code. If you cannot provide more information I don't see how this is answerable.

Comment: Are you looking to define a different uploads folder for your plug in on a different domain. Also we will need to see your relevant code.